# Phabricator-Jenkins plugin issue; Jenkins build will pass, but it will not generate any artifacts

Tags: plugins, jenkins, phabricator

I have Phabricator and Jenkins integrated. However, when I kick off a build in either Phabricator or Jenkins, there are no results. My goal is for Jenkins to generate .jar files as artifacts after I kick off a build of Java code. I did try to configure Jenkins with post-build actions to "archive the artifacts." That however causes the builds to fail because there are no artifacts. I am doing a parameterized build. The builds pass, but nothing is generated. The build executes successfully, but as I understand it there should be something generated as a result of that build (jars/wars). My issue is that is not happening at all. As I understand it, Jenkins should generate some artifact after a successful build. However, there are no artifacts showing up in Jenkins

In Jenkins, the build output is:

```
`Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/DansItem/workspace
 [phabricator:ignore-build] No differential ID found.
 [phabricator:plugin-provider] 'cobertura' plugin not installed.
 [phabricator:non-differential-harbormaster] Sending diffusion result as: SUCCESS
 Finished: SUCCESS
`
```

There is nothing in the workspace for that build. Looking at Jenkins documentation, building Java code should result in some .jar .war files. My Jenkins build creates nothing.
 In Phabricator, there is an artifact tab, that is just a link back to Jenkins:

![Phabricator artifacts tab][1]`

I have tried setting the post build actions to archive the artifacts, but whenever I set a post build action, the build fails. I have tried just setting a single wildcard (*) character, and the job fails saying there are no artifacts found. The build fails regardless of what I set the files to archive in the post build actions.

![Jenkins Post build actions for "/**/*.jar"][2]

![Jenkins Post build actions for "/**/*.jar"][3]

Comment: This looks for me like your jenkins job is just not well configured. What kind of job is it? We need some more information on this, if it triggers a maven build, maybe the maven configuration is not correct? What happens, if you trigger the job manually?

Comment: It is a parameterized build.  The build is manually triggered in Phabricator.  Whenever I set the post build actions to archive the artifacts, the build fails saying that artifact does not exist.  I am trying to kick off a build of some Java code; simple "Hello World" stuff.   I'm just trying to get Jenkins and Phabricator configured correctly. I followed the directions from the Phabricator-differential plug-in Jenkins wikie page: https://github.com/uber/phabricator-jenkins-plugin